# Showing a function is decreasing

Tags: functions

I have $$a_{n} = \left|\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{n\pi} x^{-p}\sin{(x)}~\mathrm{d}x\right|$$ and want to show this is monotonically decreasing, how would I do this? Note $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p>0$.

Comment: Consider using \left| and \right| to get brackets that automatically fit the height of the expression. You can also use \left( and \right) as well as \left\{ and \right\} and lots of others. They must come in left-right pairs.

Comment: Consider editing your own post to fix this error.

Comment: This sequence converges to $0$, but it is not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Can you explain why @Mhenni_Benghorbal? Remember we are talking about $a_{n}$ alone not just $f(x)=x^{-p}sin{(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}x^{-p}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|
&=\left|\,\int_0^\pi(x+n\pi)^{-p}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&=\int_0^\pi(x+n\pi)^{-p}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Compare pointwise as $n$ gets larger.